# Does Java Compiler include String Constant Folding?

Tags: java, string, constants, compiler-optimization, constantfolding

I found out that [Java supports constant folding of primitive types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264178/what-is-constant-folding-in-java-compiler), but what about `String`s?

**Example**

If I create the following source code

```
out.write(""
        + "<markup>"
        + "<nested>"
        + "Easier to read if it is split into multiple lines"
        + "</nested>"
        + "</markup>"
        + "");
```

What goes into the compiled code?

Combined Version? `out.write("<markup><nested>Easier to read if it is split into multiple lines</nested></markup>");`

Or the less efficient run-time concatenation version? `out.write(new StringBuilder("").append("<markup>").append("<nested>").append("Easier to read if it is split into multiple lines").append("</nested>").append("</markup>").append(""));`

Comment: String concatenation is about 100x faster than writing to a device. It really wouldn't matter much if it didn't (but it does)

Comment: I just tested it on my laptop and its 50x times slower.

Comment: It's actually behaviour required by the JLS. / You can see the generated code with `javap -c`.

Comment: For those who don't know, [JLS = Java Language Specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JLS_(disambiguation)).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's an easy test:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final String a = "1" + "2";
    final String b = "12";        

    System.out.println(a == b);
}
```

Output:

```
true
```

So, yes, the compiler will fold.

Answer (score 2):

The *combined version* will be used.
The compiler optimises this automatically and puts it in the String Pool.

You can prove this behaviour easily by writing this line.

```
System.out.println("abc" == "a" + ("b" + "c")); // Prints true
```

That this prints true, means that it are the same **objects**. That is because of two things:

1. The compiler optimised `"a" + ("b" + "c")` to `"abc"`.
2. The compiler puts all string literals in the string pool. This behaviour is called [String Interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning).

Comment: The first part of this behaviour is called constant expression evaluation.

Answer (score -1):

It effectively translates to:
`out.write("<markup><nested>Easier to read if it is split into multiple lines</nested></markup>");`