# Will this make the use of StringBuilder redundant?

Tags: java, string, immutability, stringbuilder, redundancy

If I do:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("somestring" + "hello" + "more strings" + "last one");
```

Is that the same as:

```
string s = "somestring";
s + "hello" + "more strings" + "last one";
```

Would it make using string builder pointless? Thereby needing to use:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("somestring");
sb.append("hello");
sb.append("more strings");
sb.append("last one");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer to your long question is "yes".

Answer (score 4):

If this is *all* your uses of `StringBuilder` in that fragment of code, it is indeed pointless. If you continue appending after the initial call to `append`, then it is not *entirely* pointless. Your last example makes a lot more sense than the first two, though.

I am assume that constants in your post are only for clarity. If they are indeed constants, the compiler will do [*constant folding*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581824/does-java-compiler-include-string-constant-folding), making the first example equivalent to

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("somestringhello");
```

Comment: Constant folding doesn't work for method calls. It does work with the `+` operator though.

Comment: @AlanEscreet I wrote the answer to the first edit of this question, where the OP got only two strings, not four.

Answer (score 2):

`StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer` should be used instead of a String "+" operation when you will be appending elements multiple times. As in:

```
String s = new String();
for(int i=0; i < x; i++){
  s += i;
}
```

Because this is going to be converted into (something along the lines of):

```
String s = new String();
for(int i=0; i < x; i++){
   StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
   sb.append(s);
   sb.append(i)
   s = sb.toString();
}
```

In each iteration (within the bytecode equivalent) you are creating a `StringBuffer` and converting it into a `String`.

There are many sources but namely; [this](http://www.venishjoe.net/2009/11/java-string-concatenation-and.html) and [this](http://www.znetdevelopment.com/blogs/2009/04/06/java-string-concatenation/) are OK. I have done a small research on this issue around 2010, and my knowledge on this issue dates back to that. If there are additional improvements since then I am not aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the compiled output of code that uses StringBuilder vs code that simply concatenates Strings, I find that the latest compilers will usually use StringBuilder regardless when it is appropriate. Having said that, note that in your first example, you would need to say 's = s + "hello"; in order to catch the result.

Answer (score 0):

StringBuilder is mutable but String is not. 
StringBuilder makes these string operation more efficient. 
For such a small work like your example, you probably won't notice the difference tho.

Comment: It's not more efficient. Due to constant folding, the `+` operator is more efficient for constants. The compiler cannot optimize method calls in this way, so `StringBuilder` will always append at runtime. Constants appended with `+` will be optimized in to a single String constant during compilation.

Answer (score 0):

In first case the fixed literal will be detected by the compiler and will be inline as a single value. like

```
sb.append("somestring" + "hello" + "more strings" + "last one");
```

will be treated as

```
sb.append("somestringhellomore stringslast one");
```

So it will append only once to StringBuilder.

In second case, it appends multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [String javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), The `+` operator is converted to `StringBuilder` anyway.

The two major differences are:

1. When you concatenate a set of literals as you have in your example. Constant folding will translate those separate Strings in to a single String at compile time, saving this operation from being performed at run time.

   `"somestring" + "hello" + "more strings" + "last one"` becomes `"somestringhellomore stringslast one"`
2. When you concatenate in a loop or other branching structure. Use of `+` will create multiple `StringBuilder` instances which will use more memory and processing power at run time. (see http://nicklothian.com/blog/2005/06/09/on-java-string-concatenation/)