# Do Java compilers calculate constant expressions during the compilation?

Tags: java, constants, compile-time-constant, constant-expression, javacompiler

I've noticed that enum values in `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit` have methods something like:
`public long toMillis(long d)  { return x(d, C3/C2, MAX/(C3/C2)); }`

Are expressions `C3/C2` and `MAX/(C3/C2)` calculated during compilation or during runtime?

Comment: During runtime.

Comment: If all these numbers are constants (`final static`) then it will be calculated at compile time

Comment: c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082971/compile-time-constants-and-variables

Comment: Yes, `C3`, `C2` and `MAX` are all constants (`final static`). Thank you very much for answers and pointing to the right questions!

Comment: The linked duplicate talks about literals, but it also applies to compile-time constants, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/2012528/14955