# Does the Java compiler do a constant folding optimization and how to check it?

Tags: java, compiler-construction

The question have been answered:
[is there any concept called "Constant Folding" in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012528/is-there-any-concept-called-constant-folding-in-java), but the page in this answered I can't find:
https://www.javaworld.com/jw-03-2000/jw-03-javaperf_4.html

so this code:

```java
class A
{
    public static void main()
    {
        int x=123;int y=234;int z=345;
        int a=x+y+z;
    }
}
```

I use javap -c to check the assemble code, it not does not do the constant folding optimization:

```
 public static void main();
   Code:
      0: bipush        123
      2: istore_0
      3: sipush        234
      6: istore_1
      7: sipush        345
     10: istore_2
     11: iload_0
     12: iload_1
     13: iadd
     14: iload_2
     15: iadd
     16: istore_3
     17: return
```

It seems javac does not have optimization options like GCC's O2, so if the java compiler does the constant folding optimization, how can I seen it?

Comment: If it's not done in bytecode, it will definitely be done in assembler should the JIT compiler decide to translate that method into machine code.

Comment: By the way, the internet archive has that article saved https://web.archive.org/web/20170707040315/https://www.javaworld.com/article/2076060/build-ci-sdlc/compiler-optimizations.html

Comment: "if java compiler do the constant folding optimization,how can I seen it?" Your previous sentence established that javac doesn't do constant folding, so this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks.so is it means that any compiler that generate code for the "stack machine" (like jvm and clr and lua vm) theoretically can't do the constant folding direct(without JIT)?

Comment: It would do constant folding if you had made `x`, `y`, and `z` final.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel That sounds strange to me. Those variables are *effectively* final and the compiler knows it. So why treat them differently when the keyword is there? (For the record, I don't doubt that it's true, it's just strange)

Comment: @Jorn Effectively final is not the same as being explicitly final. As far as I know, the JLS reserves these type of optimizations only for things that are explicitly final. See among others, [4.12.4. final Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) and [15.29. Constant Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.29). Explicitly final variables initialized with a constant expression are constants. The same is not specified for effectively final variables.

Comment: In the case of string concatenation, case expressions, and several other things, it is *required* to do so by the JLS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java compiler does perform constant folding, but only if you use literals or constant expressions, and/or if the variables you use in the calculation are `final` and have been initialised with constant expression (see among others, [4.12.4. final Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) and [15.29. Constant Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.29) of the JLS).

Modifying your code to make `x`, `y` and `z` final:

```java
class A
{
    public static void main()
    {
        final int x = 123;
        final int y = 234;
        final int z = 345;
        int a=x+y+z;
    }
}
```

After compilation, the `javap` output now is:

```
  public static void main();
    Code:
       0: sipush        702
       3: istore_0
       4: return
```

However, in general, the Java compiler doesn't do much optimizations, most of the optimization happens at runtime, by the JIT compiler, which uses information about the underlying platform (e.g. CPU instruction set), and actual runtime characteristics to decide on optimizations and compiling the code to native.

Also noteworthy: if you make `a` final as well, then it is eliminated from the bytecode as well:

```
  public static void main();
    Code:
       0: return
```